# Using valgrind to find realloc(,0)?

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind, realloc

I have a program with a lot of realloc and I'm pretty sure there's a `something=realloc(something, 0)` somewhere, somewhen. Is there some way to have valgrind (or some other method) show me the place ?

Comment: You can use Valgrind and compiler sanitizers to figure out when you go out of bounds. IIRC the information for such cases also contain information about where the memory was allocated. Doesn't your logs include that information?

Comment: Any specific reason you need to find this at runtime? I assume you have a literal 0 in the code, otherwise it's a valid question.

Comment: And if the size is fetched at runtime, why not add some input validation to make sure it can't be zero? How do you fetch or calculate the size?

Comment: You can easily do this even without Valgrind, either through text search, or through mocking/wrapping `#include "poor_mans_debugger.h"` -> `#define realloc(arg1, arg2) (assert(arg2), realloc(arg1, arg2))`

Comment: Remember all those times when someone said, "**Always** validate return codes from system functions"... `realloc( xx, 0 );` returns NULL... The cost of instrumenting one's code is always to be paid sooner or later. Seems this is a case of 'later'...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Actually `realloc(..., 0)` might return a non-null pointer, which can't be dereferenced. The behavior have been updated for C17 and C23 (in C23 it's undefined behavior to pass zero as the size).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "in C23 it's undefined behavior to pass zero as the size"... Great! So much for legacy code... Thanks... :-)

Comment: Thanks @Lundin, I found it. The reallocs were in many parts of the program for the talked about pointer, with dynamic variables. There was an off-by one somewhere.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Passing zero size to the malloc family of functions has always been questionable at best. From ISO 9899:1990: "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined; the value returned shall be either a null pointer or a unique pointer." Writing code relying on either of those results was already a bad idea 32 years ago.

Comment: @Lundin Neat "poor_mans_debugger" solution :-) Downloading the valgrind source code and compiling it is really quick too if one wants to customize it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it treat `realloc(ptr, 0)` as a "fishy" value. My sequence of `ptr = malloc(1024);` and `ptr = realloc(ptr, 0);` ends up as two `malloc(1024)` calls inside valgrind (even though the assembly code shows `call malloc` and `call realloc`). Oh well, it was worth a try ...

Answer (score 1):

There was some discussion of this in 2021 [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436413) but nothing yet has come of it.

So at the moment Valgrind does not warn about it.

My feeling is that such a feature would be useful, but I'd probably want it to be under an option and off by default.